# How to make row as header then count the populated datas

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to count all the rows which has a status of checked out, 
but I can only do is to populate it by rows then count it dynamically.

How can I make my rows as header then count the status after?

I need to make the dorm name rows as column header 
then checked out as rows.

**Query :**

```
SELECT  Room_Number as 'Room Number',Dorm_Name as 'Dorm Name',
 COUNT(IF(action = 'Checked Out' , 1, NULL)) 'Checked Out'  FROM billeting_history group by dorm_name;


+-----------+-------------+-------------+ 
| Dorm Name | Room_number | Checked Out |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+ 
| Arquitola |         205 |           1 |
| Hangar    |         201 |           0 |
| Noble     |         200 |           0 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+ 

Desired output :

+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+ 
| Room Number | Arquitola | Hangar | Noble |
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+
|         205 |         1 |      0 |     0 |
|         201 |         0 |      0 |     0 |
|         200 |         0 |      0 |     0 |
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: This is an odd request :-?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific columns you want, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Room_Number, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN Dorm_Name = 'Arquitola' THEN checked_out ELSE 0 END ) as Arquitola,
       SUM( CASE WHEN Dorm_Name = 'Hangar' THEN checked_out ELSE 0 END ) as Hangar,
       SUM( CASE WHEN Dorm_Name = 'Noble' THEN checked_out ELSE 0 END ) as Noble
FROM billeting_history 
GROUP BY Room_Number;
```

If you don't know the full list of names, then you need to use dynamic SQL.